# vector of thread-wrapper with thread bound to class member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector

I ran into an interesting issue today for which I am searching a "good" solution. I am aware of the original problem, but I am yet unable to find a solution that does not suck.

I attempted to maintain a std::vector of a class which wraps a thread. This is fine so far, as with move-semantics of C++11 we are able to do this.
Anyway, my problem resides, that the function, which is executed by the thread, is a member function of the thread wrapper class.

This yields the unforeseen problem, that due to possible moves inside the std::vector object (e.g. when internally reallocating the storage), the members of my wrapper class move perfectly, but the thread is, indeed, still bound to the object which it was moved from.

I've thrown together a small example to demonstrates my issue (see below).
However, I am aware of three possible solutions:

- preallocate the std::vector to be large enough, so avoiding reallocation
  `workers.reserve(10)` for example before creation of the threads
  **con:** not adjustable during "runtime" (after spawning threads)
- avoid moving the worker objects (thus preserving the association of the thread-bound instance and the instance that is carrying the thread), e.g. by wrapping them into a move enabled type that preserves its member:
  for example, wrapping the workers in `std::unique_ptr`, but anything like a pointer will do the job
  **con:** wasting resources and readability due to the wrapper, requires allocation per worker
- putting the thread-bound function in an other member object of the worker which is not embedded in the worker class but referenced via pointer, thus preserving the object on which the thread operates and moving that object from worker to worker.

  ```
  class worker {
    struct exec_context {
      // the whole execution context is here...
      void work() {
        // this is the thread bound function
      }
    };
    exec_context *ctx_; // allocate this in default constructor
                        // move the pointer in move constructor
    // ...
  };
  ```

  **con:** requires allocation per worker

Correct me if I am wrong, but I am almost certain about the origin of the problem, but keep struggling in finding a solution that does not suck.

---

**edit:** I do want to keep the std::vector for constant time random access.

---

As always: Thank you so much for your help! :-)

Thanks,
Sebastian

---

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::literals;

class worker
{
public:
  // default constructor, used by emplace
  worker()
    : thread_{&worker::work, this}
  { }

  // resource like handlin, forbid copy semantics
  worker(const worker&) = delete;
  worker& operator=(const worker&) = delete;

  // allow for move construction (requirement for std::vector-container)
  // will be invoked, when std::vector reallocates its internal storage
  worker(worker &&other)
    : thread_(std::move(other.thread_)),
      run_(other.run_),
      num_(other.num_)
  { }

  // we don't want (and need) move assign
  worker& operator=(worker&&) = delete;

  // indicator: if at any time we get the output 0xdead
  // we know that we are operating on an already destructed obejct
  virtual ~worker()
  {
    num_ = 0xdead;
  }

  // for the sake of completness
  void stop()
  {
    run_ = false;
    thread_.join();
  }

private:
  std::thread thread_;
  bool run_ = true;
  int num_ = 0;

  void work()
  {
    // output num_ continuesly
    while (run_) {
      std::printf("%x\n", num_);
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<worker> workers;

  // One worker is fine, but more instances will end up in reallocating of the underlying storage and thus in move construction.
  workers.emplace_back();
  //workers.emplace_back();

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);

  // again, for the sake of completeness...
  for (auto &w : workers)
    w.stop();
}
```

which indeed gives without reallocation always `0`, but with reallocation of the vectors internal space:

```
0
0
0
dead
dead
dead
dead
dead
dead
dead
dead
0
dead
```

Comment: How about std::list ?  Or std::deque if you can always add new elements are the beginning or end?  I personally would use std::unique_pointer.

Comment: That's correct, this would help. I did not mention that I do want to keep std::vector for constant time (= O(1) ) access. (updated)

Comment: I agree with Richard Critten. I don't have enough c++11 support to run your code, but if for some reason you need vector, I would expect vector<unique_ptr<worker>> to fix your issues, because the underlying object does not change, and that appears to be what your threads require.

Comment: Tanks for your replies! :-) The solution you are mentioning is what I was talking about in approach 2. It would absolutely fix the problem but as written in the original post, it obfuscates the code a little too much (one might not agree here, but it is still my opinion...)

Comment: @RichardCritten there don't seem to be better solutions. if you post your answer, I'll mark it as a solution :-)